# Java public key size

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, public-key

To interoperate with a service, I must encrypt some values using RSA with a key size that seeems smaller than the minimum of 512 bits on Java. Is there any way I can relax that policy?

```
BigInteger e = new BigInteger("13082845549543033994073971762152947067", 10);
BigInteger m = new BigInteger("229110545576645850236522690668306544921", 10);

RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
KeyFactory keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = keyFac.generatePublic(spec);

// ^^^^ java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: RSA keys must be at least 512 bits long
```

Comment: I have to question the point of such an endeavor - RSA 512 bits is already easily crackable (see [this](http://www.geek.com/news/512-bit-keys-cracked-in-6-weeks-549618/)), and that was over 10 years ago - now it wouldn't take anywhere near that long. I suppose you could use a lot of reflection to remove any such restrictions, or perhaps find a different JVM which allows such things, or maybe even implement your own RSA suite, but none of those would help the underlying security issue.

Comment: I must interoperate with this system. It's terribly bad designed, with self-signed keys and unmatching hostnames. But a programmer's gotta do what s/he's gotta do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the BouncyCastle provider. Just prepend your code with

```
java.security.Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

and change the line

```
KeyFactory keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
```

into

```
KeyFactory keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code, and I have following results:

```
SunPKCS11-NSS RSA public key, 128 bits (id 1, session object)
modulus: 229110545576645850236522690668306544921
public exponent: 13082845549543033994073971762152947067
```

Where does exception exactly occur?

Comment: It happens on the `generatePublic` call, and for reference, bitcount(e): 64
bitcount(m): 49

Comment: @wingleader: The bitcount is not the interesting quantity, the bitLength is.